# Can any total ordering on $\Bbb R$ be mapped to the standard order?

Tags: order-theory

If I have a total ordering $\succeq$ on $\mathbb R$, is there guaranteed to be a function $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g(x) \geq g(y)$ if and only if $x \succeq y$?
It seems to me that the answer should be yes, but this seems to cause an issue by allowing one to define a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to the natural numbers.

Comment: Why would that allow you to define a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N$?

Comment: But the answer is certainly no; just choose a total ordering which differs in some essential way from the usual one.  For instance, one in which there is a smallest element.

Comment: The thinking for the bijection is using a lexicographic order on $\mathbb R^2$, and then taking a bijection $h$ to $\mathbb R$, which inherits the order from $\mathbb R^2$. Each pair in $\mathbb R^2$ that differ only in the second element gives a non-empty interval in $\mathbb R$, which can be associated with a rational number. Hope that's clear/correct.

Comment: There  are uncountably many non-empty intervals, so your association of intervals with rationals cannot be one-to-one.

Answer (score 2):

The natural total order $(\Bbb R,\le)$ has the property that every family of disjoint, non-sigleton and non-empty intervals is countable. For total orders this property is hereditary, which means that the order induced on any subset must have it too. The lexicographic order on $\Bbb R^2$ does not have this property, therefore it cannot be realised as a suborder of $(\Bbb R,\le)$. However, the lexicographic order is isomorphic to some order $(\Bbb R,\preceq)$, by using a bijection $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$.